# mscdex/node-ftp - Await Promise Resolving Too Early

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ftp

I'm overly new to asynchronous functions so sorry if I get this wrong. At the current moment I've tried to upload all the folders in a given directory via FTP using mscdex node-ftp node package. Whilst this works perfectly the promise resolves too early within my function and will run other code in the main function before the upload is fully complete.

Is there a way to make code after the uploadFolder function run only after the uploadFolder function is fully complete?

```js
var c = new Client(config);

let uploadFolder = (folderToUpload) => {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let folderName = folderToUpload.substring(
        folderToUpload.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
      );

      let replacedItem = folderToUpload.replace(folderName, "");

      let uploadOrder = Glob.sync(folderToUpload + "/**/*");

      c.on("ready", () => {
        let uploadOrderFiltered = uploadOrder.map((element) => {
          return element.replace(replacedItem, "");
        });

        c.mkdir(`/${folderName}`, false, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`Error, MKDIR Error ${error}`);
            c.end();
          }
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < uploadOrderFiltered.length; i++) {
          if (uploadOrderFiltered[i].includes(".")) {
            c.put(
              `${replacedItem}${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`,
              `/${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`,
              (error) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(`Error, UPLOADING Error ${error}`);
                  c.end();
                }
              }
            );
          } else {
            c.mkdir(`/${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`, false, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log(`Error, MKDIR Error ${error}`);
                c.end();
              }
            });
          }
        }

        c.end();
      });

      c.connect(config);
      resolve();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`[FTP ERROR]: ${error}`);
    reject();
  }
};
```

```js
const { createFolder } = require("./createFolder");

let asyncFunc = async () => {

// ... CODE BEFORE (Runs Fine)

//PROMISE BROKEN
  await uploadFolder(
    "D:/GitHub/Procedural-Artwork-Generation/nexRender/Project/Output/zeroTwoTemplate_AJDKAJKDJKADJKA"
  );
  console.log("[FTP]: Upload Done");

//Upload Done is running before uploadFolder function is completed.
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You're resolving your `promise` long before any of the asynchronous operations have completed. You need to call resolve() only when you get an event that indicates all the asynchronous stuff is done. Plus, you appear to have a loop of asynchronous stuff so you can't call `resolve()` until ALL of those are done.   This problem would be easier to solve if you promisified one `.put()` operation that is used in the loop and then you can use promises to manage the control flow, completion and error propagation.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, after having a further look, finding ways to determine what function would indicate that all async commands were done I found the c.on("end") event, I've linked this one with the promise.

Comment: That's the general idea, but you appear to have a loop of asynchronous operations so you need to know when every operation in the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as jfriend00 said, I was resolving my promise too early. What I ended up doing was replacing the resolve() method with instead a separate event handler outside of the c.on("ready") block which listened for the "end" event.

The updated code for this is as below

```js
var c = new Client(config);

let uploadFolder = (folderToUpload) => {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let folderName = folderToUpload.substring(
        folderToUpload.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
      );

      let replacedItem = folderToUpload.replace(folderName, "");

      let uploadOrder = Glob.sync(folderToUpload + "/**/*");

      c.on("ready", () => {
        let uploadOrderFiltered = uploadOrder.map((element) => {
          return element.replace(replacedItem, "");
        });

        c.mkdir(`/${folderName}`, false, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`Error, MKDIR Error ${error}`);
            c.end();
          }
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < uploadOrderFiltered.length; i++) {
          if (uploadOrderFiltered[i].includes(".")) {
            c.put(
              `${replacedItem}${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`,
              `/${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`,
              (error) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(`Error, UPLOADING Error ${error}`);
                  c.end();
                }
              }
            );
          } else {
            c.mkdir(`/${uploadOrderFiltered[i]}`, false, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log(`Error, MKDIR Error ${error}`);
                c.end();
              }
            });
          }
        }

        c.end();
      });

      c.on("end", () => {
        resolve();
      });

      c.connect(config);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`[FTP ERROR]: ${error}`);
    reject();
  }
};
```

Comment: How does this actually wait for all your uploads to finish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow exactly everything you're trying to accomplish, but I think this code could be a lot simpler if you used the `promise-ftp` library which wraps promises around the node-ftp library and then you can use `async/await` for flow control on all your asynchronous operations.

Here's the general idea for how that would look (I tried to copy your logic without really understanding what you're doing and without an ability to test it - so take this as directional, not as something that runs right out of the box):

```
const Client = require('promise-ftp');
const glob = require('glob-promise');

async function uploadFolder(folderToUpload) {
    let folderName = folderToUpload.substring(folderToUpload.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    let replacedItem = folderToUpload.replace(folderName, "");
    let uploadOrder = await glob(folderToUpload + "/**/*");
    const c = new Client(config);
    try {
        await c.connect();
        await c.mkdir(`/${folderName}`, false);
        let uploadOrderFiltered = uploadOrder.map((element) => {
            return element.replace(replacedItem, "");
        });
        for (let f of uploadOrderFiltered) {
            if (f.includes(".")) {
                await c.put(`${replacedItem}${f}`, `/${f}`);
            } else {
                await c.mkdir(`/${f}`, false);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('FTP error: ', e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        c.end();
    }
}
```

A few observations about your logic:

1. You seem to be assuming that the presence of a "." in the filename indicates its a file, not a directory.  There is certainly no guarantee of that as directories can have "." in them.  It would be better to get that information from your original file system, perhaps from your Glob call.
2. You're using the synchronous version of Glob.  There is `glob-promise` which wraps promises around the glob interface so you can also use `async/await` with it and then use the asynchronous version.
3. Your original code creates one client object ahead of time and stores that at the module level, then reuses it.  That would create problems if there was ever more than one call to `uploadFolder()` in progress at once.  So, I created a new Client for each separate call to `uploadFolder()`.
4. This new version communicates back errors to the caller via the returned promise so the caller can both know when it's done and if there were errors.  Your code was not communicating back most errors to the caller.